# Some format in MyEclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, code-formatting

I use MyEclipse for making projects on JAVA. When I create a new class in MyEclipse, it creates the class in this format:

```
class  A {

}
```

ie; It puts the " { " in the same line, in which it puts "class A". But I want this in this format:

```
class A
{

}
```

I know this doesn't matter a lot. But If can occur, it will be more comfortable for me.

Answer (score 2):

1. Navigate to <kbd>Window</kbd> > <kbd>Preferences</kbd> > <kbd>Java</kbd> > <kbd>Code Style</kbd> > <kbd>Formatter</kbd>
2. Tap <kbd>New...</kbd> button
3. Enter "Profile name"
4. Tap <kbd>OK</kbd> button
5. Select <kbd>Braces</kbd> tab
6. For "Class or interface declaration" drop-down, select <kbd>Next line</kbd>
7. Tap <kbd>OK</kbd> button
8. Tap <kbd>OK</kbd> button

Answer (score 1):

you can edit this behaviour in Window -> Preferences-> Java -> Code Style -> Formatter